Question Regarding Lebesgue Integrable
I am reading Royden's Real Analysis(5th edition), and confusing about the definition of Lebesgue Integrable.
Here is the definition in chapter 4.2: A bounded function defined on a measurable set is said to be Lebesgue integrable or simply integrable, provided that
$$\sup_{\varphi\leq f}\int_{E}\varphi dm=\inf_{f\leq\psi}\int_{E}\psi dm$$
where the infimum and supremum are taken over finitely supported, simple functions on E. The common value of the infimum and supremum is called the Lebesgue integral, or simply the integral of f over E.
In chapter 4.5, it defines that: A measurable function $f:E\mapsto\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ is said to be integrable provided that $\int_{E}|f|<\infty$
I'm confusing that why don't we all use the second definition?

By and large, we do use the second definition.  Are you instead asking why the first definition is proposed at all?

I presume it was for pedagogical purposes.

Unlike other books, Royden develops the Lebesgue integral in stages.  The first definition applies to the integral of a bounded, measurable function over set of finite measure.  In a later section, he extends the definition to nonnegative measurable functions which may be unbounded and where the integral may be taken over a set of infinite measure.  Finally, he defines the integral for general measurable functions.  The integral is always defined although it may be infinite.  "Integrable" means what you wrote" $\int_E |f| < \infty$. At least that is how it's done in the 4th edition.

@RRL what is the advantage of defining the bounded measurable function over set of finite measure and use it to approximate non-negative measurable function. I’m asking this because it’s more straight forward for me to use non-negative simple function to approximate.

@BrianMoehring yes this is exactly what I’m asking for

@BrianMoehring: Even more confusing,  you will find that Royden changes how he presents integration from one edition to the next.  His book also has two parts where he first develops Lebesgue measure for sets in $\mathbb{R}$. and integration for measurable functions of a singler eal variable. He then completely does it all over again in part II  for integration over general measure spaces.  The latter is probably how most people now learn the subject.  Part I is a transition from the Riemann integral.  He defines upper and lower Lebesgue integrals analagous to Darboux integrals.
